# Check if child value exist - Firebase / React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working on a React.js project, trying to check if a specific email exist in my Firebase DB before executing some function.

In this example, i've got 2 different emails "jonh@doe.com" and "bob@ford.com" from the "users" table. Each user has a specific ID like this one : ZJ9SeEQviZdISg4zxWKzRLjsBXX2

```
-users
   -ZJ9SeEQviZdISg4zxWKzRLjsBXX2
      -infos
         -lastname: "Doe"
         -firstname: "John"
         -email: "john@doe.com"
   -DhDNNsk6dhdnDKllLnnBSVSVsXbs
      -infos
         -lastname: "Ford"
         -firstname: "Bob"
         -email: "bob@ford.com"
```

Here is my code :

```
firebase.database().ref().child('users').orderByKey().once('value', 
snap => {

  snap.forEach(child => {

    if("my@email.com" === child.val().email){
      formIsValid = false;
    }

    ...
```

I want to check if "my@email.com" exist, but I don't really know how to do it. I'm pretty sure it's not so hard to do...

Thank you very much for your help !
Val

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not querying by the correct child property. You'll need something like thisL

```
firebase.database().ref().child('users').orderByChild('infos/email').equalTo('my@email.com')
  .limitToFirst(1).once('child_added', snap => {
    if("my@email.com" === snap.val().email){
      formIsValid = false;
    }
})
```

This orders the child nodes by the value of their `infos/email` property, and then filters them. To run this efficiently, you'll need to define an index:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      ".indexOn: "infos/email"
    }
  }
}
```

As an extra trick, this code uses `limitToFirst(1)` and `child_added` (instead of `value`), since you only care about the existence of a matching child.

Comment: humm, not sure to understand. I tried your solution by using equalTo but nothing happened.

Comment: Yeah, I now noticed you have an `infos` in there. I updated my answer to use that i the `orderByChild` call.